# In Tradingview Pine Editor, what happened to the utility to automatically convert v4 scripts to v4 and v4 scripts to v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I had the feature earlier this week but it seems to be missing now. Web browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is still there.

Click on the three dots and you should see it. If not, restart your browser or PC.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen as well.  The reason was the indicator was read only.  There is a solid black lock on the code.

I had to make a copy.  This unlocked it and I could convert.